# assertRaises for method with optional parameters

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm using `assertRaises` for [unit test in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/).

Example method I want to test:

```
def example_method(var, optional_var=None):
    if optional_var is not None:
        raise ExampleException()
```

My test method:

```
def test_method(self):
    self.assertRaises(ExampleException, example_method, ???)
```

How should I pass the arguments to raise the exception?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Two ways to do it:

1. **Just like in the question but putting the args**:

   ```
   def test_method(self):        
       self.assertRaises(ExampleException, example_method, "some_var", 
                         optional_var="not_none")
   ```
2. **With `with`**:

   Like explained in [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises):

   ```
   def test_method(self):
       with self.assertRaises(ExampleException):
           example_method("some_var", "not_none")
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Also there is more neater and cleaner way with using lambda:

```
def foo(name):
    if name == 'shams':
        raise ValueError

# then in your test case
self.assertRaises(ValueError, lambda: foo('shams'))
```